# No se puede eliminar un directorio. El método delete() devuelve false

Tags: java, archivo

Intento eliminar un archivo file. El caso es que no se borra.
He leído algunos post y sugieren que se cierren todos los flujos. He cerrado todos los flujos que he abierto.
El problema sigue persistiendo.

Os dejo mi código:

```
public void borrarLibros() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        File filePsicología = new File("librosPsicologia.obj");
        File filesoloPsicología = new File("librossoloPsicologia.obj");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePsicología));
        ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filesoloPsicología));
        try {
        Libro libro;
        int contadorEliminados=0;
        while((libro = (Libro) ois.readObject())!=null){
            ous.writeObject(libro);
            if(libro.getTipo().equals("psychology")) {
                ous.writeObject(libro);
            }
            else {
                contadorEliminados++;
            }
        }
        if(contadorEliminados==0){
            System.out.println("No se ha eliminado ningún objeto");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Se han eliminado:"+contadorEliminados);
        }
        }
        catch (EOFException exc) {
        }
            ois.close();
            ous.close();
        System.out.println(filePsicología.delete());//He cerrado todos los flujos pero devuelve false.
        filesoloPsicología.renameTo(filePsicología);
        
    }
```

Comment: Revisa si tienes permisos para borrar el archivo `filePsicología.getParentFile().canWrite()`, revisa también si el archivo existe `filePsicología.exists()`. Ambos te darán booleanos.

Comment: El primer método devuelve este error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.canWrite()" because the return value of "java.io.File.getParentFile()" is null
 at Ejercicio4.Libro.borrarLibros(Libro.java:150)
 at Ejercicio4.Main.main(Main.java:48)

Comment: El segundo devuelve que existe,osea true

Comment: Mmm, extraño. ¿Qué tal si pruebas con `Files.delete(filePsicología.toPath());`?

Comment: Listo gracias, esa es la solución, si puedes por favor publica una respuesta de como has llegado a esa conclusión para que los demás usuarios puedan apreciarlo

Comment: No agrego respuesta porque realmente no sé la causa de que no te funcionara lo que tenías anteriormente. En teoría el archivo existía, tenías permiso de eliminar en la carpeta y cerraste los recursos, deberías poder haber sido capaz de eliminarlo sin errores. Simplemente te ofrecí una solución alternativa y me alegro mucho que te haya funcionado.

Comment: Muchas gracias! que tengas una buena tarde !!